# Binary search that continues without ending

Tags: python, search, recursion

I was given the following code segment to debug. I know the error is that it keeps on running without stopping but I do not know how to correct it. I was wondering where I should look?

```
 def str_search( data, target, start, end ):

    if start == end:
        return None

    mid_index = ( start + end) // 2
    mid_value = data[mid_index]


    if target == mid_value:
        return mid_index
    elif target < mid_value:
        return str_search( data, target, start, mid_index)
    else:
        return str_search( data, target, mid_index, end)
```

Comment: Plz post your test data which makes your program run forever.

Comment: `print(str_search("hello",'h',0,4))`

Comment: See my answer for detail. Come on. Vote me up and accept my answer. You should have a look at the book "Programming Pearls". One of the chapter talks about binary search in detail and how you can make less such coding errors.

Comment: Now this is weird `return str_search( data, target, start - 1, mid_index - 1)
    else:
        return str_search( data, target, mid_index , end + 1)` came out with the proper results.

Comment: Don't try this. It is just coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid running forever, you should shrink your target each step by using

```
str_search( data, target, start, mid_index - 1)
```

and

```
str_search( data, target, mid_index + 1, end)
```

A good practice is to print out the target and search range each step.

Also make sure your to check your boundary condition by

```
start > end
```

because 'mid_index - 1' may be less than 'start'.

Comment: I still seem to be getting a run time error that states max depth of recursion reached in comparison.

Comment: How about now? I made a typo just now.

Comment: So I ran these test cases `print(str_search("hello",'e',0,4))
    print(str_search("hello",'o',0,4))
    print(str_search("hello",'h',0,4))` The first returned None, and the other two called themselves forever.

Comment: A prerequisite of using binary search is that its target is sorted. Otherwise, it makes no sense to compare data[idx] and target. "hello" should be sorted to "ehllo".

Comment: In the actual program, an random string is generated. If there is no target, it will print not found. There is no sorting. The only error lies in the search function itself right now.

Comment: You cannot use binary search on an unsorted target.

Comment: So I asked someone else and they said to look at the way mid_idx is being calculated each time. I am not too sure how that helps.

Comment: Nevermind, I am a dummy. There was more documentation that said the precondition was that the string must be in alphanumeric order.

Comment: Alphanumeric order means sorted in a certain way. "hello" is not but "ehllo" is. For your real problem "random string is generated. If there is no target, it will print not found" you should not use binary search to just look for an character. Use normal search provided by python library.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like

```
mid_index = ( start + end) // 2
```

will only calculate the correct mid index when start=0

shouldn't it be

```
mid_index = ( end - start) // 2
```